# How to decompose a MIMO system into a multiplication minimum and nonminimum phase part

Tags: matlab, control-theory

suppose the transfer function of m-input-m-output system is
$$G\left( s \right) = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{g_{11}}\left( s \right)}& \cdots &{{g_{1m}}\left( s \right)}\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{{g_{m1}}\left( s \right)}& \cdots &{{g_{mm}}\left( s \right)}
\end{array}} \right]$$
Each ${g_{ij}}(s)$ might contains nonminimum phase part.Then, how could the system be decomposed into the multiplication of minimum ${G_{\min }}\left( s \right)$ and nonminimum phase part ${G_{non\min }}\left( s \right)$
$$G\left( s \right) = {G_{\min }}\left( s \right) * {G_{non\min }}\left( s \right)$$
Is there any command in MATLAB to realize it?

Comment: There is no unique way of doing this, it will only tell you how to split the zeros, but not the poles.

Comment: If $m=1$, then it is easy to decompose by simply finding the unstable zeros. However, for MIMO system, even if I can find unstable zeros for each $g_{ij}(s)$, it's still hard to obtain the final multiplication form.

Comment: So you do not care if one of the final transfer functions is not causal, otherwise you still also have to choose how to split up the poles, even for $m=1$.

Comment: What if I do not care about whether it's causal. Is there any simple method to realize the decomposition? Could you give me some hint about that @KwinvanderVeen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the zeros of a transfer function as the values for $s$ at which it loses rank (also known as transmission zeros) then you could make use of the [Smith McMillan form](http://csd.newcastle.edu.au/appendices/AppendixB.pdf). Namely by multiplying any MIMO transfer function matrix by its pole polynomial one can obtain a  polynomial matrix $P(s)$. Any polynomial can be written as

$$
P(s) = U_1(s)\,D(s)\,U_2(s)
$$

where $U_1(s)$ and $U_2(s)$ are [unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix) (does not lose rank for any $s$) and $D(s)$ is diagonal (does loses rank at $s$ equal to a zero). This diagonal matrix can be split up into two diagonal matrices, one with only right half plane zeros and the other with only left half plane zeros.

For example

$$
G(s) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{s^4+s+1}{(s^2+1)(s+1)(s+3)} & \frac{1-s}{(s^2+1)(s+3)} \\
\frac{s-1}{(s+1)(s+3)} & \frac{1-s}{(s^2+1)(s+1)(s+3)}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

can also be written as

\begin{align}
G(s) &= \frac{1}{(s^2+1)(s+1)(s+3)}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & s+1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
s+2 & 0 \\
0 & s-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
s^2+1 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \frac{1}{(s^2+1)(s+1)(s+3)}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & s+1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
s+2 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & s-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
s^2+1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Multiplying the left unimodular matrix with the left diagonal matrix and the right diagonal matrix with right unimodular matrix and distribute the terms of the pole polynomial gives

$$
G(s) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{s+2}{s+1} & 1 \\
0 & \frac{1}{s+1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{(s^2+1)(s+3)} & 0 \\
\frac{s-1}{s+3} & \frac{1-s}{(s^2+1)(s+3)}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Of course you could use a different distribution of the pole polynomial and you could throw any two unimodular matrices, which are each others inverse, in-between the two two diagonal matrices. So splitting a transfer function matrix into a minimum phase and non-minimum phase part will in general not be unique.